# Caching only images in browser without .htaccess file in java Application

Tags: java, servlets, caching, wicket

**Here is the java Code**

```
WebResponse response = getWebRequestCycle().getWebResponse(); 
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=31536000,must-revalidate"); 
response.setHeader("pragma", "max-age=31536000");
```

**Here is the html page where image need to be cached**

```
<HTML>
<head></head>
<BODY>
<div><img src="images\banner1.png"/></div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image is managed by Wicket (i.e. its url in the final page looks like `.../wicket/resource/com.example.MyComponent/some.img`) then you can use Wicket's ResourceSettings to configure the default cache duration and caching strategy.

E.g. in YourApplication#init() do: `getResourceSettings().setDefaultCacheDuration(Duration.days(180))`.

If the image is not managed by Wicket then you should use Servlet Filter that adds those response headers for all static resources you want. See http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/advanced-extras.html for Jetty and https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/filter.html#Expires_Filter for Tomcat.

Comment: thanks in tons its worked for me .i wonder your an astute in apache wicket .i worked on it for 15 days finally i made it by u thanks a lot